Can I combine the two integrals in the calculation of $\mathbb{E}[X_1]-\mathbb{E}[X_2]$?
According to Wikipedia, the expected value of a continuous random variable can be calculated by,
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^{\infty}(1-F(x))dx-\int_{-\infty}^0F(x)dx$$where $F(x)$ represents the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the random variable $X$. I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_1]-\mathbb{E}[X_2]$ assuming the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the CDFs $F_1(x)$ and $F_2(x)$ respectively:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1]-\mathbb{E}[X_2]=\left(\int_0^{\infty}(1-F_1(x))dx-\int_{-\infty}^0F_1(x)dx\right)-\left(\int_0^{\infty}(1-F_2(x))dx-\int_{-\infty}^0F_2(x)dx\right)$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1]-\mathbb{E}[X_2]=\int_0^{\infty}\left(F_2(x)-F_1(x)\right)dx+ \int_{-\infty}^{0}\left(F_2(x)-F_1(x)\right)dx$$
From here, I'm wondering if it is correct to combine the two integrals into one and say: $$\mathbb{E}[X_1]-\mathbb{E}[X_2]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(F_2(x)-F_1(x)\right)dx$$

It can help to rewrite the improper integral expressions as limits.

Yes, this would be generally correct, but some care is needed.
To be pedantic and to show all the implicit assumptions, we may note that the improper integral over the real line can be defined as:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \text{d}x \triangleq \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \text{d}x
$$
so from the properties of limits and integrals we have:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \text{d}x - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \text{d}x \triangleq \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \text{d}x - \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^{a} g(x) \text{d}x \\= 
\lim_{a \to \infty} \left( \int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \text{d}x - \int_{-a}^{a} g(x) \text{d}x \right) \\= 
\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^{a} \left( f(x) - g(x)\right) \text{d}x \triangleq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( f(x) - g(x)\right)\text{d}x
$$
Where the first and last equalities are by definition (marked with $\triangleq$) and we need two more assumptions:
A) the second equality requires that both limits (and thus improper integrals) exist and are finite and
B) third inequality requires that both functions are integrable over $[-a, a]$ for all sufficiently large $a$.
For CDFs, A) may not necessarily hold (when the expected value is not well defined), so you need to separately ensure the finiteness of the integrals/expected values. (e.g. the difference of two i.i.d Cauchy variables has undefined expectation, but the difference of their CDFs integrates to 0)
However B) will always hold as all CDFs are (Reimann) integrable over any interval, because the set of discontinuities of any CDF has Lebesgue measure 0.
You can slightly extend the validity by noting this identity holds for infinite integrals in the special case where the integrals diverge to infinities of opposite sign, but this requires a separate line of reasoning as infinite limits are really a different thing than finite limits.
